# Can I use Blender to create an open loop race car track level?

Tags: modeling, objects

I've just used Blender to design my 3d model of a vehicle.  Now I would like to create the race track.  It will be an open loop track where the start and finish are not connected.  Is this something for which I should be using Blender?  Or is this done in another program?  Google research has been unclear.

Comment: You certainly can use blender for that. Better question is what do you want to do with this race track? Does this need to be some specific architectural drawings with measurements CAD style? Or are you just making a setting to render you car in? If the latter, then yes by all means make it in blender.

Comment: just a racetrack for a video game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As J.Doe yes you definitely can! There's even tutorials on that exact task,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDLLbKvEeBY

Although this specific video is on a loop track making an open one wouldn't be much different I don't think. Of course depending on what you're actually trying to do you may need to look for more specific tutorials, like if you're making it for animation inside blender or if it's intended for a game or perhaps you want terrain around your track, there's tutorials out there for a lot of tasks in blender if you need them. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**
The modeling and texturing tools of Blender enable you to create environments. (Including streets)